# Defining AutoScaling for Aurora DB Cluster in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

I need to add AutoScaling for my AWS Aurora DB Cluster, and I found this [nice article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html) about how to do it with the web console. But I couldn't find how to define it using CloudFormation template of the `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` resource.

Can someone direct me on how to define Auto Scaling Policies to my DB cluster using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Application Autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html#Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.AddCode) service. Below is an example CFN script but note that I haven't created any instances - only the cluster and the scaling policy.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  MyDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora
      EngineVersion: 5.6.10a
      MasterUsername: example
      MasterUserPassword: examplepassword

  AutoScalerTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MinCapacity: 1
      MaxCapacity: 8
      ResourceId: !Sub "cluster:${MyDatabase}"
      ScalableDimension: rds:cluster:ReadReplicaCount
      ServiceNamespace: rds
      RoleARN: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/rds.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_RDSCluster"

  AutoScaler:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalerTarget
      ServiceNamespace: rds
      PolicyName: Example
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalableDimension: rds:cluster:ReadReplicaCount
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: RDSReaderAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleOutCooldown: 300
        ScaleInCooldown: 300
        DisableScaleIn: False
```

Also, take a look at [aurora serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/).

Comment: This will do the job. Thanks! :)

Comment: How do you configure the instance type in this setup (like db.t2.small) ?

Comment: In fact, this approach does not seem to work anymore.
As the docs says : "Before you can use Aurora Auto Scaling with an Aurora DB cluster, you must first create an Aurora DB cluster with a primary instance and at least one Aurora Replica."